# How to configure an interface in /etc/network/interfaces to start in monitoring mode?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, iwlwifi

I want an interface to run only in monitoring mode and configure it through `/etc/network/interfaces`

**How do I configure my interface through `/etc/network/interfaces` to start in monitoring mode?**

To make things clear, I am looking for the equivalent of

```
airmon-ng start wlan1
```

but setup automatically in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

---

An solution would be to put the previous command in a `/etc/network/if-up.d` but I am looking for a more formal way of doing it.

from `man wireless`, the mode is set with the field `wireless-mode '. This solution is not valid

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
[...]
auto wlan1
wireless-mode Monitor
[...]
$ /etc/network/interfaces:41: misplaced option
ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
```

PS: running on Debian 8.0

Comment: Run these commands: `airmon-ng` ,  `airmon-ng check` , `airmon-ng check kill` and then `airmon-ng start wlan1`

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking to put it in *monitor* mode, or *promiscuous* mode? There is a difference between those two:

### Definition

[**Monitor mode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode)

Sniffing the packets in the air without connecting (associating) with any access point. Think of it like listening to people's conversations while you walk down the street.

[**Promiscuous mode**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode)

Sniffing the packets after connecting to an access point. This is possible because the wireless-enabled devices send the data in the air but only "mark" them to be processed by the intended receiver. They cannot send the packets and make sure they only reach a specific device, unlike with switched LANs.

Think of it like joining a group of people in a conversation, but at the same time being able to hear when someone says "Hey, Mike, I have a new laptop". Even though you're not Mike, and that sentence was intended to be heard by Mike, but you're still able to hear it.

[*(credit for these definitions to Adi)*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/37000)

### Howto

Since I guess you'll want promiscuous mode, rather than monitor mode in `/etc/network/interfaces`, I'll tell you how:

**Promiscuous mode**

If you want to do it in `/etc/network/interfaces`, check out this configuration:

```
iface eth0 static
address 192.168.2.1
up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 promisc on
```

The last line is the relevant one. It puts eth0 in promiscuous mode as soon as it comes online ('up').

Comment: Thanks for your answer which I'll use, but I am really looking for a monitor mode as initiated by `airmon-ng start wlan1`.

Comment: Sure! No problem. What distro are you using?

Comment: Debian Jessy 8.0. Thanks again for your help. `wireless-mode Monitor` does not work even if `wireless-mode ad-hoc` is correct for Ad Hoc network.

Answer (score 1):

This configuration brings wlan0 into monitor mode at startup (Jessie).

```
#/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
  wireless-mode monitor
```

But I think airmon-ng also uses interface mapping.

[Addition] It works right using pre-up command

```
auto mon0
iface mon0 inet manual
  pre-up iw wlan0 interface add mon0 type monitor
  wireless-mode monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

> To make things clear, I am looking for the equivalent of
>
> `airmon-ng start wlan1`

You can add a monitor interface through `iw` command:

```
iw phy phy1 interface add mon1 type monitor
```

To capture with `mon1` interface , you can delete `wlan1` interface

```
iw dev wlan1 del
```

Enable `mon1`

```
ifconfig mon1 up
```

Set up the frequency:

```
iw dev mon1 set freq put_the frequency_here
```

Check it with `iwconfig mon1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am however looking for a configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`. I guess I'll end up putting those commands in `ifup.d`